# Erro ao dar build com o Jenkins e o MSBuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, jenkins, integração-contínua

Estou tentando criar um job de build no Jenkins, já configurei a pasta onde ele busca o **MSBuild.exe** e também o plugin porém na hora que eu coloco ele para rodar dá esse erro: `

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Teste\ControleEstoque.Web\ControleEstoque.Web.csproj(403,5):
>   error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.

Estou colocando os seguintes parametros no comando de build

```
/p:Configuration=Release /t:build /p:DeployOnBuild=True
```

Porque o **MSBuild** está reclamando do **NuGet**? Ele já vem instalado ou não?

Comment: Você configurou  algum plugin para o Nuget? Você pode adicionar uma execução do restore no batch command direto com o executável dele, procurar um plugin, ou simplesmente copiar a sua pasta packages com as bibliotecas já baixadas para o diretório do projeto no jenkins... Mas sempre que adicionar ou remover uma nova você teria que fazer essa equalização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, dando uma pesquisada percebi que o Nuget tem que ser instaldo.

Então eu instalei ele e coloquei ele no diretório raiz da minha máquina `"C:"`.

Lá nas configurações do JOB de build adicionei em um novo passo antes de entrar no comando ***( Na opeção de Executar no comando Windows )*** de build, que foi justamente esse comando:

`C:\Nuget\nuget.exe restore "Caminho da minha solução"`.E funcionou